# How to get a notification in tomcat AFTER a servlet is ready to serve? (ServletContextListener is early)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I want to receive notification on startup when a servlet is loaded by tomcat and ready to serve.   I'd like to make an http call to this servlet in this notification.

I've tried adding a `ServletContextListener` to my web.xml, but when I receive the contextInitialized callback, the servlet doesn't seem fully loaded, and I get a 404 when I try to make an http call to it.

edit:

If I put a sleep for about 20 seconds before I make the http call (on another thread so as not to block) in myServletContextListener. contextInitialized() impl, it works fine. So I'm pretty sure I'm getting the event before the servlet is ready to call.

```
public class StartupListener implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {

    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Thread.sleep(20000L);
            Target target = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://localhost:8080/myapp");
            target.path(endpoint).request().get(String.class);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {

}
```

}

Comment: Maybe load-on-startup and specify high number on last servlet, it acts as a final bootstrap handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reliable way to determine that a servlet is ready to handle requests.
From §2.3.1 of the servlet (3.0) spec:

> The servlet container is responsible for loading and instantiating servlets. The loading and instantiation can occur when the container is started, or delayed until the container determines the servlet is needed to service a request.

The `ServletContextListener.contextInitialized(...)` method is invoked when your web application has been started, and is not related to the lifecycle of individual servlets.

You could possibly post some kind of notification at the end of the servlet's `init` method, recognising that your servlet is only *nearly* ready.

Alternatively, you may be able to achieve what you want by writing extensions to `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext` and `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper`, but this is outside the realm of normal application development.

Answer (score 0):

servlet gets loaded for the first time mapping request is made to server, 404 indicates that something is wrong either in deployment or request URL

Comment: If I put a sleep for about 20 seconds before I make the http call (on another thread so as not to block) in my`ServletContextListener. contextInitialized()` impl, it works fine.  So I'm pretty sure I'm getting the event before the servlet is ready to call.